# Load csv into S3 from local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am exploring AWS sagemaker for ML. I have created a bucket:

```
bucket_name = 'test-bucket' 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
try:
   if  my_region == 'us-east-1':
      s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
   else: 
      s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration={ 'LocationConstraint': my_region })
print('S3 bucket created successfully')
except Exception as e:
    print('S3 error: ',e)
```

I have a csv in my local and I want to load that into the bucket I created.

All the links I have referred  have directions to load it from a link and unzip it. Is there a way to load the data into the bucket from the local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Amazon SageMaker you can use the SageMaker python library that is implementing the most useful commands for data scientists, including the upload of files to S3. It is already installed on your SageMaker notebook instance by default.

```
import sagemaker
sess = sagemaker.Session()

# Uploading the local file to S3
sess.upload_data(path='local-file.txt', bucket=bucket_name, key_prefix='input')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS CLI. Not sure why you are coding all this in python. If you want to create infrastructure use either CloudFormation or Terraform.

Here is how you use AWS CLI

> aws s3 cp /path/localfolder s3://bucketname/foldername --recursive

See here how to set up CLI

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html

Answer (score -1):

**Uploading file**s from the local machine to a target S3 bucket. See below for an example:

```
import boto3 bucket_name = 'my-bucket' content = open('local-file.txt', 'rb') s3 = boto3.client('s3') s3.put_object( Bucket=bucket_name, Key='directory-in-bucket/remote-file.txt', Body=content )
```